# Can a tank be hit when it is not visible?

Tags: world-of-tanks

Can I hit a tank that I'm not seeing but whose position is known to me? If yes, does the hit reveal him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can totally hit tanks without them being visible on the map. This is sometimes done by artillery or even tank destroyers. They scan the area for the usual hideouts, look for movement or gun trace, and fire.

Tanks that are hit by splash damage or direct hits will not be lit up, but you will know when you get a kill.

This is why it's very important for arty and base defenders to change positions, if they have been spotted by an enemy scout. Good enemy artillery take note of your position. They don't need to actually see you on the map, as long as they know your last position.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can hit tanks that are not visible. The hit itself won't make them visible, but it might cause the target to move and lose any camo bonuses, and that might make him visible.

If you fire and can carefully watch your tracer and it disappears in mid-air, then you may have hit the tank that is not visable. If you can see your tracer hit the ground or an object, then you missed.

Comment: Very interesting fact; the shot disappearing when you hit the tank that is not visible

Comment: @SysDragon: note that the shot disappears mid-air if the shell exits the maximum rendering distance too.